# Swift - FirstViewController and GKGameCenterControllerDelegate

Tags: swift, game-center

I want to include a GameCenter Leaderboard in my app but I have one problem.

When I want to show LeaderBoard, I use this code :

```
//shows leaderboard screen
func showLeader() {
    var vc = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
    var gc = GKGameCenterViewController()
    gc.gameCenterDelegate = self
    vc?.presentViewController(gc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

For that, I must had GKGameCenterControllerDelegate in my class like that :

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {
```

When I do that, I have an error : 'type FirstViewController' does not to conform to protocol 'GKGameCenterControllerDelegate'.

Any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the following method:

```
 func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gcViewController: GKGameCenterViewController!)
    {
        // By tapping on Done, the Game Center window will be dismissed.
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

More info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKGameCenterViewControllerDelegate_Ref/